# W8.1 unable to check for update from admin account

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-update

I have a windows 8.1 computer that I have found at my job which is unable to update even when logged in as local admin. There is no networked account.

[image: I am logged in as admin but unable to force an update]

Comment: Is this computer connected to a domain?  Just becaue you are logged into as a local Administrator means nothing if its connected to a domain and the account isn't also a domain Administrator

Comment: @Ramhound its not connected to a domain, we use mainly macs in the office.